# Locale-indepenent string to float conversion in python

Tags: python, locale, string-conversion

I need to convert string to float, but there can be different input string formats, such as `'1234,5'` or `'1234.5'` or `'1 234,5'` or `'1,234.5'` or whatever. And I can not change locale decimal pointer or thousands separator, because I may not know what data I will get in advance.

Is there a way or method or library to parse and convert to float this kind of locale-specific values without knowing which locale is used?

P.S. Is there any solution exists for the same problem with dates?

TIA.

Comment: Do the strings always have a decimal separator of some kind?

Comment: They should but they also may not

Comment: ok, can there be more than two decimal places?

Comment: If that is the case then your problem cannot be solved as there can always be ambiguous cases. No library can help you with that! The best you can do is convert all clear cases, and report back on ambiguous cases with possible options for what the number might be. Ie. `1,234` is ambiguous and could be `1234.00` or `1.234`

Comment: Hm, I will think about proposing a minimum of valid variations, thank you.

Comment: Great. Once you narrow that down, and remove ambiguous cases, it should be relatively easy to solve.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362121/convert-python-strings-into-floats-explicitly-usng-the-comma-or-the-point-as-sep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some assumptions on which character is the thousands separator and which is the decimal point. However, there is a case where you cannot know for sure what do do:

- Look for the last character that is `.` or `,`. If it occurs more than once, the number does not have a decimal point and that character is the thousands separator
- If the string contains exactly one of each, the last one is the decimal point
- If the string contains only one point/comma, you are pretty much out of luck: `123.456` or `123,456` might be the number `123456` or `123.456`. However, with a number like `123.45` - i.e. the number of digits after the potential thousands separator not being a multiple of three - you can assume that it's a decimal point.

Comment: I don't want to do any heuristic analysis on the text myself, because it can lead to unpredictable results. It there's a library to do it, that would be my option.