# Convert Python strings into floats explicitly using the comma or the point as separators

Tags: python, localization, floating-point, type-conversion

How can I explicitly tell python to read a decimal number using the point or the comma as a decimal separator? I don't know the localization settings of the PC that will run my script, and this should not influence my application, I only want to say:

```
f = read_float_with_point("3.14")
```

or

```
f = read_float_with_comma("3,14")
```

I think that writing

```
def read_float_with_comma(num):
    return float(num.replace(",", ".")
```

is not secure, because I don't know the locale settings!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> because I don't know the locale settings

You could look that up using the [`locale` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html):

```
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.RADIXCHAR)
'.'
```

or

```
>>> locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']
'.'
```

Using that, your code could become:

```
import locale
_locale_radix = locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']

def read_float_with_comma(num):
    if _locale_radix != '.':
        num = num.replace(_locale_radix, ".")
    return float(num)
```

Better still, the same module has a conversion function for you, called [`atof()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.atof):

```
import locale

def read_float_with_comma(num):
    return locale.atof(num)
```

Comment: This will use the locale settings, which is maybe not what diegogb wants. What if you need to output/parse data in a different locale as the current? The locale module explicitly discourages changing the locale in a library, so this method is only valid for simple scripts.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: for simple scripts or desktop GUI programs or anything else that doesn't need to serve multiple (networked) clients.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: but the OP specifically wanted to know what the PC on which his script would run would use, so this is exactly what was wanted. Which is why the OP marked this answer as accepted; their problem was solved.

Comment: Well, not really: the OP wanted to force a format independent of the current locale. Which means, either reinvent the wheel implementing his own function to parse with comma or dot, or force a locale which uses what he needs in each case. But changing the locale is discouraged and slow, so any application implemented using this locale change should only do it once (ideally at the start of the application). This application will be very inflexible: it will only  parse / output in a pre-defined format, and changing it will require a restart. I do not see how this can be good for a GUI.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: sure, [using `locale` can be painful](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats). But I've understood the question to be: I want to know what separator the locale uses when representing the floating point numbers. What other options are there to query the OS for that information?

Comment: using only _locale_radix is a very dangerous step.

Comment: @iliasiliadis: in what way is it *very dangerous*?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters **using only** is the key point. Converting a string like *"1.000.000,000"*, **using only** the radix, to *"1.000.000.000"* will make the code unusable.

Comment: @iliasiliadis: that's just a simple bug. Nothing *dangerous* about such a bug.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters If proposing to users a way for creating, in their code, known-in-advance bugs is not a "_proposing something dangerous_" then ok.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `locale.atof`

```
import locale
locale.atof('12.3')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/babel.numbers#babel.numbers%3aparse_decimal) to parse decimals in local formats:

```
>>> parse_decimal('1,099.98', locale='en_US')
Decimal('1099.98')
>>> parse_decimal('1.099,98', locale='de')
Decimal('1099.98')
```

Comment: As http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html#parsing-numbers states in a note: **Number parsing is not properly implemented yet**