# How to parse floating point number arguments passed via CLI?

Tags: python, command-line, floating-point

As you know floats use different decimal separators on different locales. But I wonder if I should care when user passes floating point in native locale.

At first I thought I should try to parse input using portable 'C' locale and then on the ValueError exception (I'm using Python) I should try parse it as native float.

But what could be the consequences of this? Is it good idea at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362121/2647279) seems to have some good information. But your application is a command line application, I would not bother to use localization, and simply require a decimal point. This is standard in practically every programming language.

Comment: By standard in "practically every programming language" you mean that sources of the program requires dot to be decimal point?

Comment: Yes, every language that I am aware of (except for Excell maybe) uses the American system of a dot as decimal separator.