# How to read string as a float which has a comma in between?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code gives me a string which i can easily convert into a float value but problem arises when the value is like 2,325.45. Code throws an error saying that it is not able to read commas in a float value.I need to compare this value with a fixed value of 1000.00. How should i do that
Here is the code.

```
import pyttsx
import time
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
engine=pyttsx.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate-70)

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    req = urllib2.Request('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TCS.NS    /?p=TCS.NS')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    #print the_page
    page=soup(the_page,"html.parser")
    new=page.findAll("span",{"class":"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"})[0].string
    print new
    engine.say(new)
   engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: `b = float(a.replace(',', ''))` is one way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python strings into floats explicitly using the comma or the point as separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362121/convert-python-strings-into-floats-explicitly-using-the-comma-or-the-point-as-se)

Answer (score 2):

You should firstly remove the comma `,` from the number string and then you should type-cast it to `float`. For example:

```
>>> num_str = '2,325.45'
>>> float(num_str.replace(',', ''))
2325.45
```

Answer (score 0):

using `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> num_str = '2,325.45'
>>> float(re.sub(',','',num_str))
2325.45
```