# Can't Convert Object to Float. What's the Best Workaround?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling to convert an object to a float.

```
df_final['INBCS'] = df_final['INBCS'].astype(float)
```

It keeps saying: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,620,000'

If I try a different approace, I get mostly NAN results.

```
print(pd.to_numeric(df_final['INBCS'], errors='coerce'))
```

I tried one more approach, and I still get errors.

```
df_final = df_final[df_final['INBCS'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

There are no NANs in the data; I already converted them to zeros.  When I print the data, it shows commas, but there are no commas at all.  I even did ran a replace function to get rid of any potential commas, but again, there are no commas in the data.  Any idea what's wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a few rows of, saw a `df_final.to_csv("...")` output as text? It sounds like there are commas.

Comment: There are no commas.  Here are the first 10 records. 1620000
1620000
1620000
1620000
470000
470000
2000000
2000000
2000000
10038230

Comment: what does `df_final[df_final["INBCS"].str.contains(",")]` look like?

Comment: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: If I run this: df_final["INBCS - iBwave Sqft VENUE - Capacity"].str.contains(",")

I get mostly True, and a few False and even a couple Nan.

Comment: If that is returning True anywhere, then you have commas in your `pd.Series`, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't convert that string to a float is that Python doesn't know what to do with the commas. You can reproduce this easily:

```
>>> float('1,000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,000'
```

It's tempting to just remove the commas and parse the number, but there's an internationalization concern. In *some countres*, a comma separates thousands (eg, "1,000,000" is one million). In other countries, commas separate decimals (eg, "1,05" is one and five one-hundredths).

For that reason, it's best to use localization to parse a number like that if you can't get it in a native form. [See this answer for details on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362121/convert-python-strings-into-floats-explicitly-using-the-comma-or-the-point-as-se).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you have `,` there, you can do:

```
df_final['INBCS'] = df_final['INBCS'].replace(',','')
df_final['INBCS'] = df_final['INBCS'].astype(float)
```

should work.

Comment: The problem is that in some countries, a commas separates whole numbers from fractions in decimal notation.

Comment: I agree, and that's true. But given the (lack of) information presented above, this is indeed a way to fix the error.

Comment: The OP states in his question: "I even did ran a replace function to get rid of any potential commas, but again, there are no commas in the data. "

Comment: i just read properly and realised that. Please don't accept my answer as the one.

Comment: I just tried this, again, and I still get the same error.

Comment: I think maybe it's best if you add a sample of your data so that people can play around with it. @ASH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = '1,620,000'

decimal = float(''.join(string.split(',')))

print(type(decimal), decimal)
# Prints (<type 'float'>, 1620000.0)
```

This first gets rid of all the commas using `split(',')`, then recreates the string using `''.join()`. Finally, it converts the whole thing to a float using `float()`.

Comment: Replacing commas with nothing is problematic, because in some countries, commas separate decimal points. Eg, '1,05' is one and five hundredths.

Comment: I agree, and that's true. But given the (lack of) information presented above, this is indeed a way to fix the error.

Comment: @KenKinder I assume from the question that `,` are not used as decimal points.

Comment: I would use a simpler construct to remove commas: `float(string.replace(",",""))`. But as others point out, there's internationalization concerns.

Comment: @RufusVS True, but there's already an answer about that. I want to give the OP as many options as possible.

Comment: The OP states in his question: "I even did ran a replace function to get rid of any potential commas, but again, there are no commas in the data.

Comment: How can I loop through each record and see where the problem is?  There must be some garbage in  this field, but I can't tell what it is.  The data was sourced from Google Sheets.  You know people put all kinds of junk in Google Sheets and Excel Spreadsheets too.

Comment: @ASH Maybe try looping through each string and printing each character.

Comment: Yes, yes, how can I do that?

Comment: @ASH Well, just get the string then do `for char in string: print(char)`.

Comment: @ASH It would help if you posted your code printing out a string.