# replace dot and comma with each other from a number str in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace dot and comma with each other, currently I am using below code to get the result, but want to know if there is any better way to achieve this result

```
example   
amt = '1.233.456.778,00'
data  = float(amt.replace('.','@').replace(',','.').replace('@',','))

#output  1,233,456,778.00
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to _localise_ that value, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362121/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe, localise is for older version of python they are not supported now

Comment: `locale` is still in the latest version: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rely on switching the locale of the number, should such an API exist within Python.  If you must do the substitution manually, then use `re.sub` with lambda callback:

```py
amt = '1.233.456.778,00'
output = re.sub(r'[.,]', lambda x: '.' if x.group() == ',' else ',', amt)
print(output)  # 1,233,456,778.00
```

Note that this approach gets around the problem with your current approach, namely that if the string happens to have an `@` in it, then your logic would fail.

Comment: it works but when I tried to convert it's output  in to float it give error

Comment: @Kartikeya A float (or any numeric literal in Python) doesn't have a "format."  It looks like you're using some locale where dot is the thousands separator, and comma is the decimal separator.  Nothing wrong with that; just keep your original text float, and use my code when you want to _view_ it a certain way, in another locale.